# Upgrade WSS3 to SP2010 , missing features

Tags: migration

I am upgrading from wss3 to sp2010 (eventually to 2013) using reattach db method.

I have a custom feature in wss3, that allow user to customer the page's master page. However I don't have the feature installation file.

I only know that in WSS3, it have custom files in following path
12 hive\TEMPLATE\FEATURES
12 hive\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS

I copy those files to the 14 hive, and run the Test-SPContentDatabase command and it show error:

The feature with Id {GUID} is referenced in the database [WSS_Content], but is not installed on the current farm. The missing feature may cause upgrade to fail. Please install any solution which contains the feature and restart upgrade if necessary.

So my question is, how can I export the feature from wss3 farm, and install back to 2010 farm?

Comment: actually I don't need this feature anymore in new farm. Just want to get rid of error during upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following PowerShell script will extract the solutions for you from the old farm and drop them into a folder. You can then add the one you need to the new farm.

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") 
$farm = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFarm]::Local 

$path = Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path 
[Void]( ni "$path\Solutions" -type Directory -force ) 

$farm.Solutions |% { 
  Write-Host $_.Name 
  $solution = $_.SolutionFile 
  $solution.SaveAs("$path\solutions\$($solution.Name)") 
}
```

If you'd prefer to simply remove the references, have a look at [Solving [MissingSetupFile] errors from SharePoint HEalth Analyzer](http://etienne-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/solving-missingsetupfile-errors-from.html) which contains some PowerShell to remove stale references. Note that at the bottom of that page there are links to solutions for other types of errors reported, namely missing web parts, missing aseembly and missing feature.

Comment: This is not a farm solution but a site features, can I export it?

Comment: How was the solution installed on the original farm? Or was it a feature that was manually installed to the farm server? Cab you explain s bit more about how the feature was made available on the original farm?

Comment: It was installed by previous developer we don't have document of it. I only have the customized files that is in the \FEATURES and \LAYOUTS folder. In Center Admin, I cannot found this feature in Farm Solution. But in every site , I can find it in the Site Features.

What the feature does is it add a link in the Site Setting -> Look and Feel. which linked to a aspx file (custom file in \layouts\) that can change the page master page. 
Not sure if it installed by Site Create event handler, because every time I create a blank new site, the features is already there...

Comment: In which case I'd use the feature admin tool referenced in the link I mentioned originally. That will allow you to remove the feature and also examine things like feature receivers.

Comment: Yes. finally i use the FeatureAdmin tool to remove it. Great tools. Thanks Andy!